# Unable to uninstall python package with pip (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, pip, python-requests, uninstallation

When running `pip uninstall requests` I get:

```
Uninstalling requests-2.22.0:
  Would remove:
    /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests
    /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests-2.22.0-py3.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
```

Then: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'utils.py'`

What to do?

Comment: sudo pip uninstall??

Comment: I tried that, it throws this error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.main'`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Now pip is updated to pip3(for python3.x). You can now use either pip or pip3.

Now use **`python3 -m`** to run required modules:

```
python3 -m pip3 uninstall requests
```

or you can use sudo:

```
sudo python3 -m pip3 uninstall requests           (not recommended)
```